# Small problem when taking information from a field and showing it in a message in the Android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, toast, findviewbyid

You can see that I created this simple screen on Android:
[image]

Code:

> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     EditText identifier = findViewById(R.id.identifier);
>     Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
>
>     String identifierIntoString = identifier.getText().toString().trim();
>
>     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), identifierIntoString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> }

Please, what to do so that when a user types something in the field, and then clicks on the button, it appears what the user typed to the Toast.makeText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes as per below.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String identifierIntoString = identifier.getText().toString().trim();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), identifierIntoString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.